# Encoding returning one more byte for european character

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8

If I encode the following string as UTF8:

café

It's returned as 5 bytes instead of 4. I'd like it to return 4 bytes if possible.

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
string testString = "café";
Byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(testString);
```

Returns:

```
[0] 99
[1] 97
[2] 102
[3] 195
[4] 169
```

Whereas "cafe" returns only 4 bytes.

Comment: ? What is your expectation? Do you expect UTF8 to convert "é" to "e"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up converting `UTF8` to `ISO8859-1` and it's now returning 4 bytes instead of 5.

```
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
string testString = "café";
byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(testString); // 5 bytes

Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
byte[] isoBytes = iso.GetBytes(testString); // 4 bytes
byte[] convertedUtf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes); // 4 bytes

string msg = iso.GetString(isoBytes);
string msgConverted = iso.GetString(convertedUtf8Bytes);

Console.WriteLine(msg);
Console.WriteLine(msgConverted);
```

Outputs:

café

café

Answer (score 3):

You can't with a normal encoding scheme.

You need to create a custom encoding with the desired code page, like this:

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(437);
byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes("café");
```

Output:

```
{ 99, 97, 102, 130 }
```

é is 130 in [code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).

Assuming you are going to be decoding it, you'll need to decode it with the same encoding. Otherwise you'll get strange results.

Answer (score 3):

é is Unicode U+00E9.  Unicode characters U+0080 to U+07FF take up two bytes in UTF8.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf8 for more details.

If you want only 4 bytes, then you can't use UTF8.  In theory you can use [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)  which is a single byte character encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Characters in UTF-8 can take from 1 to 6 bytes. So for your case "é" takes 2 bytes.
You can read more about UTF-8 here: [UTF-8, a transformation format of ISO 10646](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629)